# Bootstrap button is not responsive - does not resize properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have an image with a button associated it, which launches a pop-up. When I test this on mobile, the button doesn't appropriately re-size with the image. You can see this by looking at the snippet below or on JSFiddle and trying to resize the screen. As you resize, you'll see that the image and button get out of sync, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Can you please provide some guidance?

Thanks!

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KingOfTheNerds/e49Lok12/2/)

OR

```css
/* Isotope Items
---------------------------------- */

.filters {
  margin: 0 0 30px 0;
}
.filters .nav-pills > li {
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
}
.filters .nav-pills > li + li {
  margin-left: 0px;
}
.text-center.filters .nav-pills > li {
  margin-right: 2px;
  margin-left: 2px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
}
.isotope-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
.isotope-item {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}
.isotope-item .btn-default {
  color: #999999;
}
.isotope-item .btn-default:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
}
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  .filters .nav-pills > li {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
  }
}
/* Images Overlay
----------------------------------------------------------------------------- */

.overlay-container {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: -1px;
  left: 0;
  right: -1px;
  background-color: rgba(85, 172, 238, 0.9);
  cursor: pointer;
  overflow: hidden;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.8);
  transform: scale(0.8);
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: all linear 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: all linear 0.2s;
  -o-transition: all linear 0.2s;
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
}
.overlay:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.overlay span {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  bottom: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 13px;
  font-weight: 300;
}
.overlay i {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 1x;
  color: #ffffff;
  margin-top: -8px;
  margin-left: -8px;
  text-align: center;
}
.overlay-container:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-6 col-md-3 isotope-item bridesmaid">
  <div class="image-box">
    <div class="overlay-container">
      <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/200/" alt="">
      <a class="overlay" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project-1">
        <i class="fa fa-search-plus"></i>
        <span>Hover Info</span>
      </a>

    </div> <a class="btn btn-default btn-block" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#project-1">Person</a>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Please Check this Link it may help in this i just define

```
img
{
width:100%;
}
```

[Try Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/e49Lok12/3/)

Comment: Thanks @priya786 - It appears that this works on the JSFiddle, but when I put it into production and test on Chrome's mobile emulator it still has the same problem. Could the issue be w/ Chrome's dev tools or something else in the CSS?

Comment: could you show me the demo please it is easy to reslove me issue